# How to use the distribution of an estimator?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm pondering about two test questions that I wasn't able to answer and I hope that someone can help me with that.

Let us assume a multiple linear regression model $Y=X \beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$.
It is known that the maximum likelihood estimator for $\beta$ is given by
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y.$$

I was able to show that the estimator is unbiased and to calculate its variance as well. Furthermore, as a linear transformation of the normal random variable $\epsilon$ it also follows a normal distribution.

Then there were two questions I couldn't answer:

1. How can we use the information about the distribution of $\hat \beta$ rather than just the estimate itself to gain information about the regression coefficients $\beta$?
2. Say we add a new input $x$ and use the given model to estimate the new observation $\hat y = x \hat \beta$. Again, I was able to get the distribution of $\hat y$, but I couldn't say what it was good for.

Maybe someone can help me understand?

Comment: The test is leading you in the direction of deriving the Kalman Filter technique.  The point is that the maximum likelihood values for the regression coefficients evolve with the new-point "innovation" in a relatively simple way that involves a matrix inversion, addition, and re-inversion but does not involve the previous sequence of points.  Look up Kalman Filter for more details.

Comment: In (1), you need both the numerical value of $\hat \beta$ and its distribution to get a CI for $\beta$ or to test whether $\beta = 0.$ In (2) you need to be specific whether you want to _estimate_ $\hat y$ based on $\hat \beta$ and (constant) $x$, or to _predict_ the value of $\hat y$ that corresponds to a new $x.$ Somewhere in your text, I suppose there is a section explaining the distinction.

Comment: In (2) I meant indeed to predict the value of $\hat y$.

Comment: As @BruceET rightly pointed out, in practice, a point estimate is not going to be sufficient. We must attach some confidence coefficient with our predicted value, which is nothing but CI. It is the sampling distribution that lets us know whether the estimator is unbiased or not. It is the sampling that is used in devising a test statistic. All inductive inferences are based on the sampling distribution of the statistic.